# Trying to make a recursive function to get a y/n answer from the user, but when it recurs the check stops working

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

The expected output is that it will recur until the user gives a yes or no answer, and if they give yes execute code, in this case just print `"yep"`. everything works if the user inputs `"Y"` right away, but when the input is illegal and the program asks for another input the user input check stops working.

Example:

```
(Y/N) y
yep
```

*ends*

---

```
(Y/N) illegal
```

Something went wrong, make sure you made the right input and try again!

```
(Y/N) y
```

*ends*

What am I doing wrong ?

```
def user_choice():
    answer = input("(Y/N) ")
    if answer.lower() == "n": return False
    elif answer.lower() == "y": return True
    else:
        print("Something went wrong, make sure you made the right input and try again!")
        user_choice()

if user_choice(): print("yep")
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to do this with recursion? See [Asking the user for input until they give a valid result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things:

1. You're missing the a line with the function signature in your code. I'll assume it's supposed to look like this:

```py
def user_choice():
```

2. You're not returning anything when the code takes the `else` path, so nothing gets returned when the initial choice is illegal (actually `None` gets returned). So update your function like so:

```py
    answer = input("(Y/N) ")
    if answer.lower() == "n": return False
    elif answer.lower() == "y": return True
    else:
        print("Something went wrong, make sure you made the right input and try again!")
        return user_choice()  # <-- need to return a meaningful value here
```

3. Recursion is a terrible choice for solving this type of problem. A loop is simpler to write, easier to read, and performs better:

```py
def user_choice():
    while True:
        answer = input("(Y/N) ")
        if answer.lower() == "n": return False
        elif answer.lower() == "y": return True
        print("Something went wrong, make sure you made the right input and try again!")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but can I ask how I know if my code is optimized or not ? You mentioned that a while loop performs better, but how do I reach that conclusion on my own ?

Comment: That's a big question. Fortunately it has already been asked: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/56867/why-are-loops-faster-than-recursion

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this recursively.  That's simply the wrong choice.  The solution to your immediate problem is that you need `return user_choice()` not just `user_choice()`, but an iterative solution is much smarter:

```
def user_choice():
    while True:
        answer = input("(Y/N) ")
        if answer.lower() == "n":
            return False
        elif answer.lower() == "y":
            return True
        else:
            print("Something went wrong, make sure you made the right input and try again!")

if user_choice():
    print("yep")
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not return the result of the recursion. You can use something like this.

```py
def user_choice():
    answer = input("(Y/N) ")
    if answer.lower() == "n": return False
    elif answer.lower() == "y": return True
    else:
        print("Something went wrong, make sure you made the right input and try again!")
        user_choice()

if user_choice(): print("yep")
```